# List files that match list whithout duplicates keep highest version number

Tags: bash

Sorry if this is a repeated question but I have been looking for several hours.

I have a list of files generated by

```
find /usr/lib64/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf "%f\n"
```

that print something like

```
libncurses.so.6
libaudit.so.1
libncurses.so.5
libicuuc.so.65
libnghttp2.so.14
libicuuc.so.71
```

I would like to keep only the files with the highest vesion number

```
libncurses.so.6
libaudit.so.1
libnghttp2.so.14
libicuuc.so.71
```

Thanks lot for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe with `awk`?

```bash
find /usr/lib64/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf '%f\n' |
awk -F '\\.so\\.' -v OFS='.so.' '
    $2 > vers[$1] { vers[$1] = $2 }
    END { for (lib in vers) print lib, vers[lib] }
'
```

```
libaudit.so.1
libicuuc.so.71
libnghttp2.so.14
libncurses.so.6
```

**note:** you might need to implement a more accurate operator than `>` for comparing versions, or use:

```bash
find /usr/lib64/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf '%f\n' |
sort -rV |
awk -F '\\.so\\.' -v OFS='.so.' '!seen[$1]++'
```

Comment: @oguzismail It **is** specified: _"`-F sepstring` [...] This option shall be equivalent to `-v FS=sepstring`"_ => _"`-v assignment`: [...] the assignment argument is in the same form as an assignment operand"_  => _"**OPERANDS** `assignment` [...]  The characters following the <equals-sign> shall be interpreted as if they appeared in the awk program preceded and followed by a double-quote [...]"_

Comment: Oh, okay. They could have just said it though :D

Comment: @oguzismail Yeah, their "refer to" => "refer to" => "refer to" => etc... is annoying but concise.

Answer (score 1):

You could chain some commands with a pipe, something like:

```
find /usr/lib64/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf "%f\n" | 
  sort -rn -k3 -t. |
  awk -F. '!seen[$1]++'
```

---

The code above assumes that there are always 3 fields/column separated by a dot `.` from the file names.

---

With pure bash using associative array with GNU `find` and `sort`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -A uniq

while IFS= read -rd '' files; do
  if ((!uniq[${files%%.*}]++)); then
    printf '%s\n' "$files"
  fi
done < <(
  find /usr/lib64/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf "%f\0" |
  sort -rnz -k3 -t.
)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following to sort:

> find /usr/lib64/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf "%f\n" | sort -V

To only keep the latest version:

> find /usr/lib64/ -maxdepth 1 -type l -printf "%f\n" | sort -V | uniq -f2

-f2 ignores the first two fields when comparing lines.

Comment: Sorry but this answer does not show the desired result.
It shows me only one line now.